# Solder stripped USB-C cable to Keyboard PCB

Tags: soldering, usb-c

The cable that came stock with the board had 4 wires in it. They were red black white and green. Where should I connect them? Also some pads on the right might be lifted so I don't know if it is fixable in the first place.

[image: Desoldered USB-C female port part of board (some pads on the right might be lifted.)]

Comment: Pads look lifted but may be no connects. What is on the other end of cable? Can you use multimeter to figure out what signals each wire carries and then match to known USB-C pinout?

Comment: The other end is a standard USB 2.0. Sorry, I don't have a multimeter.

Answer (score 1):

like this.

[image]

You probably only need one red and one black (not both)

I might have green and white backwards. this will prevent it from working but will not cause damage,  if it doesn't work swap them.